# Lebesgue outer measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove or disprove the following:
For any subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ we have

$$|E|_e = |\{ (x_1,\dots, x_n) \in E\colon x_n < 0 \}|_e + |\{(x_1,\dots, x_n) \in E\colon x_n > 0\}|_e$$
where $|E|_e$ denotes the Lebesgue outer measure of the set $E$.

My attempt: If $E$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the statement holds. Would this statement be false if $E$ is non measurable?

Comment: Is your question about how to prove this, or is it the question you put in your "attempt"?  (In the latter case, just note $\{(x_1,\ldots, x_n) : x_n >0\}$ has non-measurable subsets)

Comment: @BrianMoehring the question is to prove or disprove that $|E|_e = |\{((x_1,\dots, x_n) \in E : x_n < 0\}|_e + |\{(x_1,\dots, x_n) \in E \colon x_n >0\}|_e$ for any $ E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=\{x: x_n<0\}$ is measurable. Hence, $|E|_e=|E\cap A|_e+|E\cap A^{c}|_e$ for any set $E$. Now complete the proof using the fact that $A=\{x: x_n=0\}$ has measure $0$.

You now have to show that $|E\cap A^{c}|_e=|E\cap \{x: x_n>0|_e$. For this note that $$|E\cap A^{c}|_e=|E\cap \{x: x_n\geq 0|_e$$ $$ \leq|E\cap \{x: x_n>0\}|_e+|E\cap \{x: x_n=0\}|_e $$ $$=|E\cap \{x: x_n>0\}|_e.$$ The fact that $$|E\cap \{x: x_n\geq 0|_e \geq |E\cap \{x: x_n> 0|_e$$ is obvious , so we have $$|E\cap \{x: x_n\geq 0\}|_e \geq |E\cap \{x: x_n> 0\}|_e.$$

Comment: If I take $A = \{x \colon x_n =0\}$ then $|E\cap A|_e = 0$ then why should $|E \cap A^c|_e = |\{ (x_1,\dots, x_n) \in E\colon x_n < 0 \}|_e + |\{(x_1,\dots, x_n) \in E\colon x_n > 0\}|_e$ for any set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @L-JS I have added details of the argument.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you for the clarification.